# How to load a server side Module/dependency into a client side script (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am currently developing a system for a vet connected to a database in mysql. I am using Node JS.

To perform the queries I have a document called "insertNewDate":

```
//const con = require("./dataConnection.js");
import {con}  from './dataConnection.js';

console.log("New Module");
function prueba(){
    con.connect(function(err,res){
        if(err) throw err;
        con.query("SELECT * FROM cliente", function(err, results, fields){
            console.log(results[0].id_cliente);
        });
    });   
}
```

which imports from another script called "dataConnection" which requires a server side module called mysql2:

```
const mysql = require("mysql2");
import {mysql2} from "/node_modules/mysql2/typings/index.d.ts";

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "admin",
    database: "control_clientes",
    connectionLimit: 5
});
export {con};
```

I've been trying to figure out how to load the required module from the server side into the cliente side. I tried using require (it didn't work) also using the import keyword (didn't find the /node_modules/mysql2/typings/index.d.ts path where my module is located on the server side). Any ideas how to fix this or a better solution?

Comment: this isn't how you'd want to do it. You dont want the client directly accessing the database and making changes. You want to provide the client with apis that you tailor for their needs.

Comment: Typically you are not connecting to the db from client side, instead send you data from client to server via http / ajax and perform db ops on the server